# How to fix this issue "identitymodeleventsource does not contain definition for showpii" in web api

Tags: field, pii

I want to fix a Personally Identifiable Information (PII) vulnerability issue found in web applications.

I have tried implementing **IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;** in the code. But it says **identitymodeleventsource does not have a definition for showPII**

please see the attached screenshot as ShowPII is does not property of identitymodeleventsource.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.